# Are most planets hollow?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, pressure, planets, centrifugal-force, models

You bore straight down inside the Earth. The further you go, the less gravity you experience, because mass above you grow, and mass below you shrink. At the (ideal) center, gravity cancels out to zero, as you experience equal mass all around you. Right?

So, centrifugal force must, at some point, overpower the diminishing gravity, suggesting that a Hollow Earth could be the better model, as compared to our current model of a high-pressure molten iron-core.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You forgot the *pressure*. It compresses everything.
Pressure increases with depth and is maximal at the center.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Pressure does not give a directed force.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Pressure per se does not have a direction, i.e. is not a vector-valued quantity, but in this case one has to consider the *pressure gradient* $dP/dr$ which immediately tries to fill local *under-densities* to reach hydrostatic equilibrium again. The typical timescale for this, is often called the *dynamical timescale*. And a gradient of a scalar function, is the desideratum we are looking for here I think.

Comment: @OleSauffaus Any pressure related explanation aside, just contemplating on an Hollow Earth without an molten iron core: How would one be able to explain the existence of Earth's magnetic field?

Comment: Centrifugal force diminishes with radius and is zero along the axis

Comment: @Diazenylium ... Well, molten iron could still exist around the "hollow", and fulfill its magnetic duties just as well. Perhaps even explain some of Earth's magnetic anomalies as "less dense (thick) regions" ... But, I gather that I'm way off in my initial assumptions, so I should perhaps just shut up :)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question. The OP even suggests that the Hollow Earth is not a correct model, but wants to know where he's going wrong.

Comment: @pela Presumably because (i) it is only picking two effects out of many, and (ii) it shows no effort to actually do the math (even qualitatively) to see how these two effects work together.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch But if you're not a physicist, you wouldn't necessarily have any idea how to go about this, where to start, or even how to ask the right question. I think it's not only unfair to the OP, but also highly discouraging. The downvoters should rather guide how to ask (I know that some do), or we will just scare away curious people, which is a shame. We want people to be interested in physics, not to think that physicists are pricks.

Comment: @pela According to the tour page, "Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics".

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Huh? Okay, I have severely missed that part of the description. I'm mostly active on astronomy.SE, where most users are non-professionals. I think it's a shame, but of course it's not up to me, and I respect the rules laid out by others. I like answers, such as yours below, that are interesting both to laymen and to professionals.

Comment: @pela It is the first sentence on the tour page.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for rubbing it in my face ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravity decreases linearly as you move towards the center of the earth.

At the same, time, the centrifucal force decreases linearly as you move towards the center for a given angular velocity $\omega$ (it scales as $mr\omega^2$).

Thus, you will still expericence an overall linear decrease of the total force towards the center.

(Note that the centrifugal force is about $0.03 \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$, that is, about 300 times smaller than gravity.)

Comment: Yes, I didn't take diminishing centrifugal force into consideration. Thank you.
However ... On the axis of rotation, there isn't any centrifugal force at all, while perpendicular to that, the centrifugal force would be maximal, while the mass (all the way to the surface) would cancel out on both sides of that. Suggesting a long narrow hollow disc inside.
I'm so confused ... sorry :(

Comment: @OleSauffaus Only a geometric point at the center has no net gravity. Anything outside this point has some gravitational pull towards that point

Comment: According to Annie & Marc Souriau, (1989). "Ellipticity and density at the inner core boundary from subcritical PKiKP and PcP data". Geophysical Journal International. 98 - The gravity at the earth's core is 4.8 m/s2